# boost i/o streams documentation

Tags: boost, documentation

boost.org is experiencing some problems with documentation - it just wouldnt open. Is there any other resource or decent documentation on boost io streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Boost installation, full documentation is in the doc directory. For example, on my computer it is C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_48_0\doc\html\index.html

To see this documentation, it is not necessary to build the Boost library, just to extract files from archive.